# Android beam intent filter

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef, android-beam

I am creating an app to catch an android beam and startup my app instead of the designated one. Ex: beam a webpage but my app launches instead.

I tried setting the manifest with an NDEF intent filter but it doesn't seem to catch the beam and launch my activity.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below the action place this:

```
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="" />
```

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#well-known-uri

Comment: As a follow up, can we specify, in the data attribute, the uri as a mimetype?

Comment: doubt it will work as well and I haven't tested it, but if you can you would use something like:  <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>